# Is it possible to instruct bash to ignore spaces in filenames?

Tags: bash, for-loop, wildcard, spaces

I am attempting to write a bash script to unzip an archive file and destroy the archive itself. See below for the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.zip
do
    unzip -j $i
    rm -f $i
done
```

The problem I am having is that the filenames often contain spaces, which apparently seems to confound the part of bash that expands wildcards. I know that manually editing the filenames to remove spaces is effective, but since there are thousands of archives, I was wondering if there was any way to expedite the process by including into the for loop a mechanism to remove spaces from the filenames.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Spaces in filenames don't confound bash if you remember to quote them.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the wildcard expansion *is not* the part where your code is breaking. Each successive value of `$i` will contain exactly one filename, whether it has spaces or not. The part where it's breaking is on the `unzip` and `rm` lines, where you've neglected to quote the expansion of `$i`. Bash first expands `$i`, *then* performs word-splitting, and finally passes the arguments to the command. So if the variable `$i` contains `foo bar.zip`, then `unzip` will see three arguments: `-j`, `foo`, and `bar.zip`.

Comment: The reason that proper quoting (e.g., `"$i"`) fixes the issue is that bash doesn't do word-splitting inside quoted strings. So if you typed `unzip -j "foo bar.zip"` on the command line, `unzip` would only see two arguments: `-j`, and `foo bar.zip`.

Comment: My incompetence confounds even myself. Thank you immensely.

Comment: @TheRavenKing You're very welcome. I always find it handy to have a script that echos out each argument on a separate line, so that I can see what a command would see. I call mine `echo-args`, but you don't really need a script. You can just do `printf "%s\n" <your bash expression here>` to see exactly how bash will parse your expression. This will help you learn the nuances of how quoting works. And there are plenty of nuances, especially when you consider the difference between single and double quotes, command substitution, array expansions using `@`, etc.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code in the question.